How to restore desktop wallpaper to Windows Spotlight mode in C#?
Context
I have a console application in .Net 6 C# that changes the current user's desktop wallpaper to an image for a given time. I backup the current wallpaper configuration of the user by reading the registry. At the end of the givent time, I would like to restore the wallpaper configuration the user had at the beginning.
I managed to restore the image mode, color and slideshow mode but I didn't managed to restore Windows Spotlight mode yet. Ideally I'd like it to work on Windows 10, 11, Windows Server 2016, 2019 and 2022 (I realize there might be differences between thos environments).
Question
How can I restore a desktop wallpaper configuration to Windows Spotlight mode in C#?
Tried Solution
I tried setting the following registry key but it did nothing:
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Wallpapers\BackgroundType = 3

Update 01/08/2024
I managed to change the Wallpaper mode to 'Windows spotlight' in the Wallpaper Personalization Settings UI but it did not effectively changed the wallpaper. Althoug the settings is shown as set, it's like the 'Spotlight manager' (or whatever handle the windows spotlight mode) is not running.
To achieve that state I applied those registry keys:
HKCU\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CloudContent\DisableWindowsSpotlightFeatures = 0
HKCU\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CloudContent\DisableSpotlightCollectionOnDesktop = 0
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Wallpapers\BackgroundType = 3
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\DesktopSpotlight\Settings\EnabledState = 1

I tried restarting explorer.exe as suggested in other posts as well a login/logout and restart the desktop but it did not change anything. I remain in this unconsistent state

How is this different from your last question?

The last question was mainly about the restoration of the slideshow mode but I need to handle the 4 modes and the spotlight is the only one remaining.

There is no winapi to set the desktop wallpaper. If you want to enable the Windows Spotlight mode, you could try to edit the Registry Key. You could add DWORD called DisableWindowsSpotlightFeatures in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CloudContent. You could set 0 to enable the Windows Spotlight.

It doesn't seem to be enough. Although I see the new value in registry (and relaunch explorer.exe as suggested on other posts), the current wallpaper type does not change.

I suggest you could refer to the Doc:AllowSpotlightCollection
Note:Windows spotlight is available on Windows Enterprise and Education editions only.

Thank you for your suggestions, I saw it as well but it does not seem to change anything. I'll update the question with wha I found

According to your update, when you set 'Windows spotlight' in the Personalize your background,it didn't change the wallpaper effectively? It seems related to your system. What version of Windows are you using? Refer to the Doc:Configure Windows spotlight

I'm using Windows 11 professional (24h2). When I change it manually in the Personalize your background, it works well. But when I do it via code and registry value updates, and open the Personalize your background,  eventhoug I see that it changed from Image (for exemple) to 'Windows spotlight' but the wallpaper did not change (not even after restart nor the day after)

Set DisableWindowsSpotlightFeatures to 0 means Windows spotlight features are allowed and may be controlled individually using their corresponding policy settings. It means that Windows spotlight will be available as an option in settings.
